# Delete Row From GridView using cancel Image

Tags: c#, asp.net

hello friend i have a requirement in which i want to delete a row from my gridview on image button delete.
i write the code like this

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView2" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" Width="200" GridLines="None" OnRowCancelingEdit="GridView2_RowCancelingEdit" OnRowDeleting="GridView2_RowDeleting" >
                                                <Columns>
                                                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Sl.No">
                                                        <ItemTemplate>
                                                            <%# Container.DataItemIndex + 1 %>
                                                        </ItemTemplate>
                                                    </asp:TemplateField>
                                                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Supportiong Documents">
                                                        <ItemTemplate>
                                                            <asp:Label ID="lblSupportingDocument" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("SupportingDocument") %>'></asp:Label>
                                                        </ItemTemplate>
                                                    </asp:TemplateField>
                                                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Delete" ShowHeader="false">
                                                        <ItemTemplate>
                                                            <asp:ImageButton ID="imgbtnDelete" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/images/delete.png" CommandName="Cancel" />
                                                        </ItemTemplate>
                                                    </asp:TemplateField>

                                                </Columns>
                                            </asp:GridView>
```

and my code behind is

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      if (!IsPostBack)
        {
           if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.QueryString["id"]) == false)
            {
                bind_SupportingDocumentGrid(id);

            }

        }
    }

void bind_SupportingDocumentGrid(int id)
    {
        List<TblFinancialTransactionSupportDocumentDetail> lstFTSD = ServiceAccess.GetProxy().GetAllFinancialTransactionSupportDocumentDetails();
        var x = (from y in lstFTSD
                 where y.FinancialTransactionId == id
                 select new
                 {
                     y.SupportingDocument
                 }).ToList();
        GridView2.DataSource = x;
        GridView2.DataBind();
    }
protected void GridView2_RowDeleting(object sender, GridViewDeleteEventArgs e)
    {
        List<TblFinancialTransactionSupportDocumentDetail> lstFTSD = ServiceAccess.GetProxy().GetAllFinancialTransactionSupportDocumentDetails();
        Label lblSupportingDocument = (Label)GridView2.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("lblSupportingDocument");
        var x = (from y in lstFTSD
                 where y.FinancialTransactionId == Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["id"]) &&
                 y.SupportingDocument == (lblSupportingDocument).ToString()
                 select new
                 {
                     y.FinancialTransactionSupportDocumentDetailId
                 }).ToList();
        ServiceAccess.GetProxy().DeleteFinancialTransactionSupportDocumentDetail(Convert.ToInt32(x));
        bind_SupportingDocumentGrid(Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["id"]));
    }
```

but somehow it is now working and i found using breakpoint is "GridView2_RowDeleting" event is not generating.
kind help me to overcome from this problem.
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have a button whose CommandName is "Delete":

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Delete" ShowHeader="false">
   <ItemTemplate>
      <asp:ImageButton ID="imgbtnDelete" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/images/delete.png" **CommandName="Delete"** />
   </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try giving handles along with the event

```
protected void GridView2_RowDeleting(object sender, GridViewDeleteEventArgs e) Handles YourDeletebutton.click
```